# Vanishing set of a pullback section

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, sheaf-theory, schemes

Let $f\colon X\to Y$ be a morphism of schemes and let $\mathcal{F}$ be an $\mathcal{O}_Y$-module. Let $s\in H^0(Y,\mathcal{F})$.

If I'm not mistaken, then $(f^{-1}s)_x=s_{f(x)}$ for all $x\in X$ and therefore $X_{f^{-1}s}=f^{-1}(Y_s)$.

Under which assumption can I make similar statements about the pullback section $f^*s$? Is it enough to require $X$ and $Y$ to be Noetherian and to restrict to the case $\mathcal{F}\in\text{Pic}(Y)$?

My motivation for the question is [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/206273/68241) on Mathoverflow which in my eyes seems to suggest that such a statement exists.

Comment: If we take "vanishing" to mean "maps into $\mathcal{F} \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_y} k(y)$" then yes. Use the description of $f^*$ on affine opens to show that if $f(x) = y$ then $(f^*\mathcal{F}) \otimes k(x) \simeq (\mathcal{F} \otimes k(y)) \otimes_{k(y)} k(x)$.

Comment: I don't understand your definition of vanishing. I define $X_{f^*s}$ to be the open set of all $x\in X$ such that $(f^*s)_x$ is not contained in the maximal ideal of $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$.

Comment: $(f^*s)_x$ is an element of $(f^*\mathcal{F})_x$, so I don't understand yours either! I think in the end we're probably trying to say the same thing. I used the version I did because it led into the second part more easily.